# .png Image Information

Tags: c++, c, png, image

Where can I find image information such as width, height and rgba pixels in a .png image?
I found it quite easy to do so with a bitmap image but png images look way too complicated. Wikipedia won't help either. (probably because of my bad English)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of writing your own PNG renderer, you probably should use an existing library (such as [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)) to do it for you.  libpng has functions such as `png_get_image_width`, `png_get_image_height`, and `png_get_rows` to get the width, height, and image data respectively.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out but I wish to write my own library.

Comment: @Pilpel: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?  Particularly when you've already determined that the wheel is complicated?

Comment: @Pilpel: If you want to implement everything yourself, you will have to implement zlib/deflate decompression as well, because PNG always compresses its payload data.

Comment: Because the wheel is forcing me to use file reading functions from the C standard library, and it has many functions I don't need. It could be more complicated than reading from a bitmap file but it should still be doable...

Comment: @Pilpel: libpng is open source.  So you can always just study its source code.

Comment: After seeing datenwolf's comment and seeing that libpng is the official library to png images I give up on trying to figure out how to build my own png library. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

The .png file format is much more flexible than .bmp, so there's not a fixed place where you can find the width and height. The more serious problem is that the pixel values are compressed, they must be uncompressed before you can use them. This almost guarantees that you'll need a library to use .png files.